# Why doesn't Python's _multiprocessing.SemLock have 'name'?

Tags: python-2.7, semaphore, python-multiprocessing

## My Environment

- Python **2.7.3**
- Ubuntu 14.04
- Source code I use: [CPython on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython)

## More Background Info to Understand My Question

As for my understanding, `Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c` implements the internal Python object **SemLock** that is used to implement the [`multiprocessing.synchronize.SemLock`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#L58) in the Python standard library:

```python
class SemLock(object):
    def __init__(self, kind, value, maxvalue, *, ctx):
        (...A lot of other code...)
                sl = self._semlock = _multiprocessing.SemLock(  # <-- Here.
```

`Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c` implements this internal **SemLock** object by defining a *SemLockObject* in C and exporting it as *SemLock* in Python.

Here is the C definition:

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    SEM_HANDLE handle;
    unsigned long last_tid;
    int count;
    int maxvalue;
    int kind;
    char *name;  /* <--- It has 'name'. */
} SemLockObject;
```

Later *SemLockObject* is exported as *SemLock*, in [Line #617](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#L617):

```c
PyTypeObject _PyMp_SemLockType = {
    PyVarObject_HEAD_INIT(NULL, 0)
    /* tp_name           */ "_multiprocessing.SemLock",
    /* tp_basicsize      */ sizeof(SemLockObject),
```

Along with *SemLock*, several _semlock_members_ are exported, too, including 'name'. See [Line #608](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#L608):

```c
static PyMemberDef semlock_members[] = {
    {"handle", T_SEM_HANDLE, offsetof(SemLockObject, handle), READONLY,
     ""},
    {"kind", T_INT, offsetof(SemLockObject, kind), READONLY,
     ""},
    {"maxvalue", T_INT, offsetof(SemLockObject, maxvalue), READONLY,
     ""},
    {"name", T_STRING, offsetof(SemLockObject, name), READONLY,
     ""},  /* <--- Here it is. */
    {NULL}
};
```

Therefore, there is a reason to believe that I can access the **name** member at run time. However, when I inspect the members of this internal *SemLock* object, I don't see the **name** member. Here is my inspection code:

```python
import multiprocessing as mp
import inspect

lock = mp.Semaphore(1)
members = inspect.getmembers(lock._semlock)
for (name, _) in members:
    print name
```

Here is the result:

```
SEM_VALUE_MAX
__class__
__delattr__
__doc__
__enter__
__exit__
__format__
__getattribute__
__hash__
__init__
__new__
__reduce__
__reduce_ex__
__repr__
__setattr__
__sizeof__
__str__
__subclasshook__
_after_fork
_count
_get_value
_is_mine
_is_zero
_rebuild 
acquire 
handle      <-- 'handle' is defined in 'semlock_members'
kind        <-- 'kind' is defined in 'semlock_members'
maxvalue    <-- 'maxvalue' is defined in 'semlock_members'
release
```

But where is **name**??

In fact, if we look at [`multiprocessing.synchronize.SemLock.__init__` Line #76](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/synchronize.py#L76), it tests the value of `_semlock.name`:

```python
if self._semlock.name is not None:
```

which makes me think the underlying _semlock has the 'name' member because otherwise the code would raise an exception like "AttributeError: '_multiprocessing.SemLock' object has no attribute 'name'".

**I must have missed something somewhere. Would someone help me point it out??**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Python 2.7, but looking at Python 3.7 source.  See [2.7's semlock_members](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Modules/_multiprocessing/semaphore.c#L587).

Comment: @yaobin, if it's not clear -- the `master`/`default` development branch long ago transitioned to support the Python 3 language.  So, if you checkout source from Github, e.g., you must go back to 2.7 to see what it looked like then.

Comment: @BrianCain Thanks for pointing out! In fact, this morning I woke up and all of a sudden it hit me: Maybe I was looking at the wrong version?? Kind of embarrassing to spend so long time posting a question and bothering so many people but which can be solved by one simple check...